# How to replace String by an image link in Java?

Tags: java, html-parsing

I am working on Java World Wind based application that uses HTML incorporated in it. I have a database containing all the places of interest with attributes like name, text_description, icon_link etc... My aim is to replace some text strings of HTML by another ones every time I click on the different place of interest on the globe. So what I need is to parse HTML document, search for a keyword and replace it by the appropriate string in my database. I have written a class that is in charge of searching for the keywords and replacing it by appropriate strings:

```
public class MyNodeVisitor extends NodeVisitor {
        String name;
        String text;
        String icon;

        public MyNodeVisitor() {

        }

        public MyNodeVisitor(String Name, String Text, String IconPath){
            this.name = Name;
            this.text = Text;
            this.icon = IconPath;
        }

        public void visitStringNode (Text string)
        {
            if (string.getText().equals("DataName")) {
                string.setText(name);
            }
            else if (string.getText().equals("DataText")){
                  string.setText(text);
            }
            else if(string.getText().equals("DataIcon")){
                     string.setText(icon);

            }
        }
    }
```

So in my HTML I have defined text strings DataName, DataText and DataIcon which I want to be replaces by text strings invoked from the database.

The above mentioned class is used in the following way in my code:

```
        NodeList nl = new NodeList();
        String htmlString = null;
        InputStream contentStream = null;
        contentStream = WWIO.openFileOrResourceStream(BROWSER_BALLOON, this.getClass());
        htmlString = WWIO.readStreamToString(contentStream, null);

      try {
            Parser parser = new Parser(htmlString);
            nl = parser.parse(null);
            nl.visitAllNodesWith(new MyNodeVisitor(resultStr2,textString,resultStr3));
            nl.toString();

        } catch (ParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        String output = nl.toHtml();
        return output;
```

Where resultStr2, textString and resultStr3 are strings that should replace the key strings "DataName","DataText" and "DataIcon" in my HTML.

The problem is that while the replacing works for the first two strings DataName and DataText (that means, everytime I am invoking different element of the database, I am getting its name and text appropriate for a concrete element), it does not work for DataIcon. Debugging says that it just simply fails to search for DataIcon String even though I have defined it in my HTMl, just like that:

```
<div class="tabbertab">
      <h2>Pictures</h2>
        <div id="album">
            <ul class="gallery">
                <li><a href="#nogo" tabindex="1">1<img  src="DataIcon" alt="landscape image 1" title="landscape image 1" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#nogo" tabindex="1">2<img  src="C:\thesis\100GreatP\eclipse_ws\test\data\pictures\1\pyramid2.jpg" alt="landscape image 2" title="landscape image 2" /></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>   
     </div>
```

I do not know what is the problem in it and I appreciate every kind of help. Thanks!

Comment: Your second link replace DataIcon seems to be working tho. But there a couple of things missing tho, for one what is nl? Because I can't see any visitAllNodesWith method, what is the use of using the nl.toString? And what is the code for the method nl.toHtml?

Comment: what does nl = parser.parse(null); does?

Comment: @Lyrion: nl is NodeList class instance, check my edited question above. All the methods visitAllNodesWith, toString and toHTML are the methods defined within this class.

Comment: @Lakshmi : the following statement will parse the html string into the list of nodes, the argument for the method parse if a Filter, in my case not defined, therefore null.